# How to wait and properly return value from async coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

I'm calling a `function` (non-suspended) from a button click. I want to run a loop in `function` using `async` coroutine and return last computed value.

My code :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    btnCount.setOnClickListener {

        var result = GlobalScope.async { dummyFoo() }
        runBlocking {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, result.await().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}

private fun dummyFoo() : Int {
    var result : Int = 0
    val waitFor = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
        for (i in 1..20000) {
            result++
        }
        return@async result
    }

    return result
}
```

Output :

I'm getting **0** in `Toast`.

I want **20000** in `Toast`.

How can I make my code to wait until loop completion and result to become `20000` and output it?

Comment: your `dummyFoo()` isn't suspend function. so, it wouldn't be suspended for `waitFor` but return immediately

Comment: I want `dummyFoo()` as non suspended, that is my requirement. I have added `runBlocking` for wait, but it is not working

Comment: then.. don't use coroutine in `dummyFoo()`. you're `dummyFoo()` would be executed as async because it is in `GlobalScope.async{}`.

Comment: Why you are using another coroutine in dummyFoo?

Comment: @Choim and @AmitTiwary : When I removed coroutine from `dummyFoo()`, it worked. Can you post your answer as it helped me

Comment: But is there any way we can use `async` inside non-suspend function and return proper result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you want to launch a CPU-intensive task off the GUI thread and then present the result in GUI. This is a basic use case of coroutines and it's solved as follows:

```
btnCount.setOnClickListener {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        val result = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            dummyFoo()
        }
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

This goes with the usual warning that you should not launch coroutines in the global scope, instead create a scope for the activity in question. Otherwise these background tasks will hog the CPU even when the user switches away from your app.

Comment: This code is giving crash `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`. Sorry to say that

Comment: It was an easy fix (see the updated code), but you _shouldn't_ use `GlobalScope` anyway.

Answer (score 7):

You should use await in dummyFoo()

```
private suspend fun dummyFoo() : Int {
    var result : Int = 0
    val waitFor = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
        for (i in 1..20000) {
            result++
        }
        return@async result
    }
    waitFor.await()
    return result
}
```

Comment: I do not want to make `dummyFoo()` as `suspend`. So, I can't create `CoroutineScope()` from it

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I am seeing the purpose of this, but if that's what you want, replace `Dispatchers.IO` with `Dispatchers.Unconfined`

Comment: This worked, can you explain me how `Dispatchers.Unconfied` worked?

Comment: `Unconfined` doesn't change the thread at all, in this case it means everything stays on the GUI thread and blocks it. It basically turns the whole thing into a no-op.

Comment: As mentioned above, it picks up the entry thread. More on it here [link](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-unconfined.html). Thats why I prefaced with "if that's what you want" :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik @Dmitri : So, can we say `Unconfined` is similar to what `coroutineScope { }` is doing? Continuing execution on caller thread?

Comment: No, `Unconfined` is a low-level feature that removes the Dispatcher and resumes the coroutine on any thread that happens to invoke the resuming callback. `coroutineScope` is a completely different feature, its purpose is to make the current coroutine await the completion of child coroutines you start within it. It has nothing to do with the concern of threads.